# If...Else Statement always diverts to "else".

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to run a "presence check" on a radio group, to determine what happens if 1 of 2 radiobuttons are selected in the group (if statement), if the other of the 2 radiobuttons is selected instead (else if statement) or if neither are selected (else statement). The code for this is as follows:

```
if (rdbAM.isSelected()) {
        strTime = rdbAM.getText().toString();
    } else if(rdbPM.isSelected()){
        strTime = rdbPM.getText().toString();
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder WrongDateFormat = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        WrongDateFormat.setMessage("Please Select AM or PM");
        WrongDateFormat.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertWrongDateFormat = WrongDateFormat.create();
        alertWrongDateFormat.show();
        return;
    }
```

So basically, what this should do is either, set the variable called "strTime" to whatever the text of the selected radiobutton in the radiogroup is, or display an error message if neither are selected. It is instead always displaying this error message, regardless of whether either radiobutton is selected or not:

[image]

(As you can see above, the "AM" radiobutton is selected, but error is still being displayed).

Any suggestions as to why this may be would be appreciated. Please note that I am relatively new to Android development, so if it is clearly something obvious then I apologise, but I have been trying to get my head round this for several days now! If you would like to see any further code, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide it, but am trying to keep it as private as possible, so didn't want to post everything in the initial post if not necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post more of you code. Especially where `rdbAM` comes from.

Comment: I believe the correct function to use is `isChecked()`

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation the [RadioButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) extends the [CompoundButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked()) that offers the method [isChecked()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked()). However there is poorly described the difference from the method [isSelected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isSelected()) from the extended class [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) that might be confusing.

Do the following and it should work:

```
rdbAM.isChecked();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `isSelected()` go for `isChecked()`.

Answer (score 0):

A `RadioButton` is a two-states button that can be either `checked` or `unchecked`. For this compound button, you should use method `isChecked()` to know its current state.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html).

**Update your code as below:**

```
if (rdbAM.isChecked()) {
        strTime = rdbAM.getText().toString();
    } else if(rdbPM.isChecked()){
        strTime = rdbPM.getText().toString();
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder WrongDateFormat = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        WrongDateFormat.setMessage("Please Select AM or PM");
        WrongDateFormat.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertWrongDateFormat = WrongDateFormat.create();
        alertWrongDateFormat.show();
        return;
    }
```